# Returning results from within a single table ordered by how many results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table with 2 references (`user_id` and `item_id`) that I need to query to find all users with certain items.
The tricky part is, I need to order the results based on, not just the number of results they have, but based on WHICH items they have.

Here's the table:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id      | int(11)               | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| item_id      | int(11) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So my query looks like this:

```
SELECT   user_id, item_id
FROM     user_items
WHERE    item_id IN (2, 122, 132)
GROUP BY user_id, item_id
HAVING   SUM(item_id = 2);
```

Looks easy enough? Here's where the tough part comes in:

item_id = 2 is REQUIRED
item_id = 122 and 132 are OPTIONAL. Anything after 132 is also optional.

I need to order results based on:
1) if ALL of the items are found.
2) if only items 2 and 122 are found.
3) if only item 2 is found.

Here's the SQL fiddle file for fiddling: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1c1/6/0

I'm thinking, if there's some way I can setup in the, something like this: SELECT query to say

```
IF (item_id = 2 AND item_id = 122 AND item_id = 132) AS matches_all,
IF (item_id = 2, item_id = 122) AS matches_some,
IF (item_id = 2) AS matches_first
```

**EDIT with updated query**
Here's what I have so far. It's about 95% of what I need:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1c1/47

```
SELECT   user_id, item_id,
  @tmp_1 := IF(SUM(item_id = 2), 1, 0) AS tmp_1,
  @tmp_2 := IF(SUM(item_id = 122), 1, 0) AS tmp_2,
  @tmp_3 := IF(SUM(item_id = 132), 1, 0) AS tmp_3,
  @tmp_4 := IF(SUM(item_id = 126), 1, 0) AS tmp_4,
  CAST(@tmp_3 + @tmp_4 AS UNSIGNED) AS total_other
FROM     user_items
WHERE    item_id IN (2, 122, 132, 126)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(item_id = 2)
ORDER BY tmp_1 DESC, tmp_2 DESC, total_other DESC
```

A couple more details:

1) I will only have a maximum of 12 items entered, so I can assign each one it's own temp field if needed.

2) The above query works perfectly for tmp_1 and tmp_2. If we have a user with items 2 and 122, it puts those at the top of the list.
For the rest, 3-4 (3 to up to 12), I need a calculation of the number of matches, which is why I made an attempt at `CAST(@tmp_3 + @tmp_4`. I'm not sure how to get those to calculate.

3) Once I have the total calculation for items 3 - 12, then that will be the third and final item in the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Example result**
Based on the schema provided in the SQL fiddle file, here is the result that should be returned based on searching for all users with item_id's: `2, 122, 132, 126`

```
+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| USER_ID | PRIMARY_ITEM | SECONDARY_ITEM | OTHER_ITEMS |
+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| 39      | 1            | 1              | 2           |
| 54      | 1            | 1              | 0           |
| 55      | 1            | 0              | 0           |
+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Your query is total nonsense: `HAVING   SUM(item_id = 2)` ??

Comment: Dude! if you have something better, please let me know! I didn't post my question because my query is perfect. I'm trying to do something that I can't quite figure out how to do. Check out the SQLFiddle link to see how it works. `HAVING SUM(item_id = 2)` just makes sure item_id 2 exists in the results.

Comment: The `HAVING SUM(item_id = 2)` is not necessarily "nonsense". This particular expression may not achieve the desired resultset, but expressions like this are usually valid, sometimes useful, and occasionally, downright indispensable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Based on the update to your question (including the desired resultset), here's a query that returns that resultset. (This is VERY similar to the query in the inline view explained in my original answer)

```
  SELECT i.user_id                         AS user_id
       , MAX(IF(i.item_id= 2   ,1,0))      AS primary_item
       , MAX(IF(i.item_id= 122 ,1,0))      AS secondary_item
       , MAX(IF(i.item_id= 132 ,1,0)) +
         MAX(IF(i.item_id= 126 ,1,0))      AS other_items
    FROM user_items i
   WHERE i.item_id IN (2, 122, 132, 126)
   GROUP BY i.user_id
  HAVING primary_item
   ORDER 
      BY primary_item   DESC
       , secondary_item DESC
       , other_items    DESC
       , i.user_id
```

Note that the expression to calculate the `other_items` column can be extended to handle any number of other items_id values.  (You just want to be sure that the same item_id is not specified twice in there, or it's going to get "counted" twice), e.g.

```
       , MAX(IF(i.item_id= 132 ,1,0)) +
         MAX(IF(i.item_id= 133 ,1,0)) +
         MAX(IF(i.item_id= 135 ,1,0)) +
         MAX(IF(i.item_id= 137 ,1,0)) +
         MAX(IF(i.item_id= 143 ,1,0))      AS other_items
```

That's basically doing a check for each item, and then deriving a 1 or a 0, and then adding up the 1s and 0s to come up with a total.

Also note that the IF() function call is not necessary, those expression could actually be reduced to:

```
       , MAX(i.item_id= 2)                 AS primary_item
       , MAX(i.item_id= 122)               AS secondary_item
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause is not actually needed to return the correct resultset.  (But if it's there, the predicate has to match the item_id values that are being checked in the SELECT list.

Note also that the ORDER BY does not need to include the `primary_item DESC`, since our query guarantees that the value of `primary_item` will be a 1. It's sufficient to start the ordering with `secondary_item DESC`, since that can be either 1 or 0.

A covering index `on (user_id,item_id)` may speed performance, or possibly an index with a leading column of `item_id` may be better.  (Absent the WHERE clause, the query will need to inspect every row in the table, basically a full table scan, or a full index scan.)

From the resultset, it looks like you want to return a '1' if the user has one or more of the item (rather than a count of how many of a particular item he has.) If what you want to return is a count of the number of each item, then you'd replace the `MAX()` aggregate with a `SUM()` aggregate, but that's more problematic for deciphering the contents of the OTHER_ITEMS column.

Note the `HAVING primary_item` clause is what gets us only rows for those users that have at least one of the `item_id = 2`.

---

**UPDATE:**

Francis said... that query [in your original answer] is returning multiple results per user, which is not what I was after.

**A:** this is a prime example of where showing an example of the resultset you want returned would be of benefit.  Your query has both `user_id` and item_id` in the SELECT list, and no indication that you want to return only one row per user, or only one row per user_id and item_id combination.

To get that, then simply add a `GROUP BY d.user_id` or a `GROUP BY d.user_id, d.item_id` clause before the `ORDER BY` clause.

---

<strike>This isn't elegant, but I think it returns the resultset you specified.</strike>

```
SELECT d.user_id
     , d.item_id 
  FROM user_items d
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT i.user_id
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=2  ,1,0)) AS item_2
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=122,1,0)) AS item_122
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=132,1,0)) AS item_132
           FROM user_items i
          WHERE i.item_id IN (2, 122, 132)
          GROUP BY i.user_id
         HAVING item_2
          ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 DESC, 1
       ) f
    ON d.user_id = f.user_id
 WHERE d.item_id IN (2, 122, 132)
 ORDER BY (f.item_122 AND f.item_132) DESC
        , f.item_122 DESC
        , d.user_id
        , d.item_id
```

The inline view (the query aliased as `f`) does the "check" of which of the items are found for the user.

---

To see how this works, we first, we check the results of just that inline view...

```
         SELECT i.user_id
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=2  ,1,0)) AS item_2
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=122,1,0)) AS item_122
              , MAX(IF(i.item_id=132,1,0)) AS item_132
           FROM user_items i
          WHERE i.item_id IN (2, 122, 132)
          GROUP BY i.user_id
         HAVING item_2
          ORDER BY 3 DESC, 4 DESC, 1
```

The `WHERE` clause could be omitted here. For our purpose here, we're basically just getting a list of user_id, along with indicators of which of the specified items they have.

The expression inside the MAX aggregates check whether the item_id matches 2, 122 or 132, respectively, and returns a 1 or a 0. We use the `MAX` aggregate to pull out any value of 1 that we find.

We do need the `GROUP BY`, so we get a distinct list of user_id.

We use the `HAVING` clause so that users that don't have an `item_id = 2` are omitted. It could be written like this

```
         HAVING item_2 > 0
```

(adding the greater than zero, but that's not required, since we are guaranteed that item_2 will have a value of 0 or 1)

The `ORDER BY` isn't really required here (since we are going to JOIN this back to the user_items table.)  (The `ORDER BY` is only required on the outermost query.) But it does demonstrate that it is possible to get this resultset ordered.

(If this were my requirement, I might just stop here, and make use of this result set; but that's not the resultset you specified.)

We join that query (using it as an inline view, or *derived table* in MySQL parlance), to the `user_items` table, so we return row for ONLY those users that match a user_id from that query.

We need to add the `WHERE` clause, so we only pull out `item_id` values in the specified list.

And we need the `ORDER BY` to get us the resultset in the specified order.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was after. I just made an update to my question with the new SQLFiddle file, which is very close at this point, so you can kinda get a better idea of what I'm after. Looks like I just need to find out how to calculate tmp fields now.

Comment: @Francis Lewis: I recommend that you be VERY careful with user variables, and make sure you understand the order of operations. They sometimes don't work as you'd expect them to.

Comment: @Francis Lewis: it's not at all clear how the resultset from the query I provided does not meet the specification.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I don't really understand the order of operations yet as this is probably the most complicated query I've tried to put together and I've only used tmp fields on 2 other occasions.
The query you provided gives me a list of users with their items that match the query, however, it doesn't provide me with a good way to sort them based on: item 1, item 2, sum of all other items; which is what I'm after.

Comment: @Francis:  your specification was that the rows FIRST be order by users having ALL of the items, and then by having item_id=2 AND item_id=122. That's the order the query returns the resultset. The columns from the inline view provide all the information needed to get the rows sorted in the specified order.

Comment: That's true, that is how I wanted it ordered and you did accomplish that, however, that query is returning multiple results per user, which is not what I was after.

Comment: @Francis:  your query specifies both `user_id` and `item_id` in the SELECT list, so you are going to get multiple rows for each user.  If you want only one row per user, with an indication of which items he has, then use just the query from the inline view.  If you want just the distinct item_id for each user, then add a GROUP BY clause.   (This is prime of example of where an EXAMPLE of the resultset you want returned would be of benefit to everyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, my bad! I tried to explain it, but an example result set would have been a lot better.
I just edited my question with an example result set based on the schema I provided so you can see what I was after.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the resultset you added to the question.  I believe this query will return a resultset that satisfies the specification.  (This query is VERY similar to the query in the inline view explained in my original answer.)

Comment: Thanks! Just changed my selected answer to yours. Sucks to pick my own answer since neither of us gets points for all the hard work (especially since I figured it out initially by looking at how your query was developed). Ok, my next question is, what's the difference between using MAX and SUM? Do you know if one is better than the other?

Comment: @Francis, doesn't matter whether you use MAX or SUM. I went at it with the `IF()` first, then just used the `MAX` to pick up the 1 if it was there. You went with the IF() first, then used SUM, and then yours has to test whether the SUM is nonzero, and replace it with a 1. The expression in my statement could be reduced to `MAX(item_id=2)`, but I think having the `IF(item_id=2,1,0)` in there makes it a little more clear what we're doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is a rule or mapping for which fields are required and which fields are optional. If you have some kind of mathematical rule that says, I don't know, maybe id < 10 is required, everything else optional, you can do some fancy where clauses with that.

Assuming the item_id is completely random, I would recommend you create a mapping table that ranks/prioritizes your items. Maybe something like an item_rank table:

```
-------------------------
| item_id | is_optional |
-------------------------
|       2 |           1 |
-------------------------
|     122 |           0 |
-------------------------
|     133 |           0 |
-------------------------
```

Then your query is:

```
SELECT user_map.user_id, user_map.item_id,
FROM user_map
INNER JOIN item_rank
ON user_map.item_id = item_rank.item_id
    AND user_map.item_id IN (2,122,133)
GROUP BY user_map.user_id
HAVING item_rank.is_optional > 0
ORDER BY COUNT( user_map.item_id );
```

I don't exactly like this solution, but without knowing a bit more of what you're trying to accomplish at the end of the day, I can't offer a more specific solution.

On a side note, when problems are difficult, it generally means you're trying to come at them the wrong way. When I find myself in an architectural bind, I tend to always find a cleaner solution when I re-trace and think about it from the beginning. Obviously depends on how far along you are, but might be worth it.

Good luck!

Comment: A mapping table would be a bit more complicated than what I was after and it wouldn't account for every possible user input because it needs to be ordered first by matches containing ALL the results, then by matches containing the first 2 plus the highest number of other results, then by matches containing the first one plus the highest number of other matches.

Comment: @FrancisLewis Ahh I see. Can you provide a bit more background about what it is your trying to do? At a higher level I mean. Something like "I have a list of item and wants to see if a user has bought a certain set of items to determine a price point"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I came up with. I got as far as just needing to calculate any items after the first 2, so I came up with a cleaner solution than using temp fields, and one that finally works.

```
SELECT   user_id,
         IF(SUM(item_id = 2), 1, 0) AS primary_item,
         IF(SUM(item_id = 122), 1, 0) AS secondary_item,
         (IF(SUM(item_id = 132), 1, 0) + IF(SUM(item_id = 126), 1, 0)) AS other_items
FROM     user_items
WHERE    item_id IN (2, 122, 132, 126)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   SUM(item_id = 2)
ORDER BY primary_item DESC, secondary_item DESC, other_items DESC
```

So this gave me a field for the first and second items so I can see if those matched, then a count on all the rest, which there can up to 10 other items.

Then it orders based on if we have the first item, second item, then the total count of all the other items.

You can see the end result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1c1/131